# Back button not working with JQuery change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a small test for using the sliding animation in the change function in JQuery mobile, and I have the functionality working to an extent. The problem I run into is the back button does not go to the previous page..I'll go from page 1 to page 2, then once I hit back it goes to page 5. Is there something I need to manually add in my javaScript so it stores the previous page correctly?

Here is the snippet of javaScript and the [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vg7T/10/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('div[data-role="page"]').on("swipeleft", function(){
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next("[data-role=page]");
        if ( nextpage.length ) {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', nextpage, {
                transition: "slide"
            });
        } 
    });
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on("swiperight", function(){
        var prevpage = $.mobile.activePage.prev("[data-role=page]");
        if ( prevpage.length ) {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", prevpage, {
                transition: "slide", reverse: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your example works for me without an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data-url` attribute on your pages, or use the `dataUrl` property in the `change` method options.

> [**dataUrl (default: undefined)**](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change)
>
> Type: String
>   The URL to use when updating the browser location upon change() completion. If not specified, the value of the data-url attribute of the page element is used.

Here is a working example using the `data-url` attribute.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n451hgb6/)

Answer (score 0):

it might be in here

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', nextpage, {
    transition: "slide"
});
```

try `changePage` maybe?

`$.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);`

Comment: That would do the same thing. `if ( nextpage.length )` comes back false if it's 0, and true if it's greater than 0.

Comment: If nextpage.length is anything greater than 0 then it will return true, the same as checking if nextpage.length > 0.

Admittedly I don't write javascript, but that's how it works in most languages and it's working in javascript. Even changing that does not fix my issue.

Comment: I had changePage before and it wasn't working, plus changePage has been deprecated since 1.4 and is being removed in 1.5.

Comment: WhiteHat, does it work on your end? When I test this out, it's working fine for me on my browser and on my phone.